# Special characters and MediaPlayer

Tags: java, android, android-mediaplayer

I have a Uri formed like

```
Uri sound = Uri.parse("file:///pathinmymobile/a?.mp3")
```

but because of the question mark, in MediaPlayer creation throws a setDataSource problem. I've also tested without the "file://", and with

```
URLEncoder.encode("file:///pathinmymobile/a?.mp3", "UTF-8").
```

and other more combinations. Is it possible to play a file containing special characters as question marks ?

Comment: try to escape the ? like file:///pathinmymobile/a\\?.mp3

Comment: Still showing a "create failed: java.io.IOException: setDataSource failed" and returning a null reference.

Answer (score 0):

If your file is in Android assets folder. This might help

```
try {
        MediaPlayer mediaPlayer = new MediaPlayer();
        AssetFileDescriptor descriptor = getAssets().openFd("intro.mp3");
        mediaPlayer.setDataSource(descriptor.getFileDescriptor(), descriptor.getStartOffset(), descriptor.getLength());
        descriptor.close();

        mediaPlayer.prepare();
        mediaPlayer.setVolume(1f, 1f);
        mediaPlayer.setLooping(true);
        mediaPlayer.start();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```